# websocket error/network management

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am working on Backbone based application (It is also an tablet application), which uses websockets, .
Websockets are working well, but Application doesn't have any logic for error/network handing.

App should show message to user that he is disconnected, and app should retry to connect again, and once its connected back, things starts working again, like gmail.

I haven't written any server-side websocket code, and I am new to Websockets.
Is there any good article on how to handle network disconnection, reconnection for Websockets?
I am unable to find how to set timeout on Websockets, Or how to reconnect again etc.

As its an tablet app, so there will be frequent network disconnections, also App will be getting into sleep mode. Is there any special considerations or practices ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/), you can use try/catch to treat erroneous cases, like not being able to connect:

```
function connect(){  
    try{  
    var socket;  
    var host = "ws://localhost:8000/socket/server/startDaemon.php";  
    var socket = new WebSocket(host);  
        message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState);  
        socket.onopen = function(){  
             message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');  
        }  
        socket.onmessage = function(msg){  
             message('<p class="message">Received: '+msg.data);  
        }  
        socket.onclose = function(){  
             message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (Closed)');  
        }  
    } catch(exception){  
         message('<p>Error'+exception);  
    }  
}
```

I couldn't find any mention of setting timeout duration even in the WebSocket spec, that might not be possible.

Comment: I am aware about it, but what about network disconnection after connected to Socket?